# Filter data on fields in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two text fields,I want filter the data using fields. Here is my code:

```
        <input type="text" ng-model="partners.name">
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="partners.website">

    <div ng-repeat ="partners in partnersData">
        <div class="cellDiv" ng-click="showName($index)">{{partners.name}}</div>    
        <div class="cellDiv" ng-click="openWebsite(partners.website)">{{partners.website}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The info you provided is not enough if someone wants to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular built in [filter- (documentation here)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) which selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.

Basic Syntax of this is -

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

So in `ng-repeat` you have to add a filter criteria like this-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="partners.name">

<input type="text" ng-model="partners.website">

<div ng-repeat ="partners in partnersData" | filter:partners" >
```

Another option is to use custom filter where you pass the partners object in custom filter function.This is useful when your filter criteria/logic becomes complicated.

```
<div ng-repeat ="partners in partnersData" | filter:getPartners" >
```

Now implement the getPartners like this-

```
$scope.getPartners = function (partners) {
    return <some condition>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Soloution:

```
<input ng-model="search.name">
<input ng-model="search.phone">
<input ng-model="search.secret">
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{name: search.name, phone: search.phone}">
```